# Can you call in the width of the device as a variable in SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello and I am quite a beginner in SCSS, I am still learning it and I find it very unique and would help in times that I need a dynamic design in the near future.

I am curious if you can call in the device's width as a variable so that you can set the media query once the device width has been detected.

If it's possible, how? do I need more than SCSS besides HTML, CSS to do it? Thanks!

```
$hamb: 991px;
$mmenu: 992px;

@if max-width <= $hamb {
.hamburger{
    display:block;
}
.m-menu{
    display:none;
}
}

@else if max-width >= $menu {
.hamburger{
    display:none;
}
.m-menu{
    display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't use common media queries? http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32. You can use your variables in the media queries.

Comment: @ChristopheVanassche It worked when I used media queries, thanks! I will still try and look at the other answers later though

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in SCSS to detect width of device

```css
$hamb: 991px;
$mmenu: 992px;
    @media screen and (max-width: $hamb){
        .hamburger{
            display:block;
        }
        .m-menu{
            display:none;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: $menu) {
        .hamburger{
            display:none;
        }
        .m-menu{
            display:block;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will attempt this later as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) will or won't apply depending on the width of your viewport. In your (S)CSS, you've to decide what to do in the default case and *if* condition(s) of each MQ is true and then in the browser CSS will or won't apply depending on current condition(s). MQs are equivalent to ifs conditions (you also have and, or and not combinations).

In a [Mobile First](https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/) methodology, you only need 1 Media Query and 1 variable:

```css
$breakpoint: 992px;

.hamburger {
    display: block;
}

.m-menu {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }

    .m-menu{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

First 2 rules outside any MQ apply by default.
Following 2 rules in a MQ will override former rules because 1/ they've the same selectors and properties and 2/ same specificity and come *after*.

Comment: I will test this later. When I get more knowledge in SCSS, I just went to the classic CSS and still worked fine.

Comment: The only non-CSS thing is the $variable, defined line #1 and used in MQ condition :)